# Why is sulfuric acid used to seal flask with highly reactive chemicals?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I the video https://youtu.be/saANxD0cqy0?t=200 (time 3:20) NileRed states that he uses sulfuric acid to seal off flask with a mixture of pottasium dichromate and table salt. He says that sulfuric acid is used to seal off flasks with highly reactive chemicals and I could not find any reasons why.

I see sulfuric acid as a very reactive chemical, that could potentionally react with substrate causing some minor problems to purity of the final product. I also wonder why he does not use any other less-reactive seal that would not react with substarte what so ever.
Thank you for your contribution

Comment: It´s just a relatively highly viscous liquid with a low vapour pressure, that does not (as opposed to, say, vaseline, which you normally use to lube these joints) react with the content of the flask. Of course it is highly hygroscopic,  I´m not sure if it is advisable to use it.

Comment: Can I make a recommendation? Do not watch this NileRed guy to learn chemistry. That grade school dropout seems to have acquired a bit of a god complex because his boss let him work with all this dangerous stuff (before firing him). I´m not saying he doesn´t know what he´s talking, but a guy working with such stuff *alone* (both physically and regarding feedback from colleagues and supervisors) is a **big red flag**.

Comment: I agree with Karl. I cannot imagine how the guy handles this material and these Chromium vapors which are corrosive and carcinogenic. He must use a rather specially equipped lab to get rid of all that Chromium(VI) which is forbidden in usual labs. Is he still alive ?

Comment: *I know I should have ..., but ... oh well...* This guy is a health hazard to the world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sulphuric acid reacts with dichromate and table salt, forming volatile and harmful [chromyl chloride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromyl_chloride).

\begin{multline}
\ce{K2Cr2O7(s) + 4 NaCl(s) + 6 H2SO4 ->}\\
\ce{2 KHSO4(s) + 4 NaHSO4(s) + 2 CrO2Cl2(l,g) + 3 H2O}
\end{multline}

Therefore it serves as a reagent and at the same time as protection against chromyl chloride escape.

> **Safety considerations**
>
> $\ce{CrO2Cl2}$ hydrolyzes to release $\ce{HCl}$ and hexavalent chromium $\ce{Cr^{\mathrm{VI}}}$.
>
> Acute: Exposure to chromyl chloride vapour irritates the respiratory system and severely irritates the eyes, and the liquid burns the skin and eyes. Ingestion would cause severe internal damage.
>
> Chronic: $\ce{CrO2Cl2}$ can produce chromosome abnormality/aberrations and is a human carcinogen via inhalation. Frequent exposure of the skin to chromyl chloride may result in skin ulcer/ulceration.